# How to pass variables using the URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pass 2 values via URL to another page. I know how to do this however I am taking one of the values from the result of select box. I am grabbing the selected value and storing it in a variable then attempting to post this variable in the URL.

option 1 is storing the selected value.

```
<select name = 'ADDITIONALINFO' id = 'ADDITIONALINFO'>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<script>
        var sel = document.getElementById("ADDITIONALINFO");

        sel.onchange = function()
        {
            var option1 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            alert(option1);
        };
        </script>

        <?php


        echo "<div class=\"add-button-quote\"><a href=\"/quotation/index.php?sku=" . $product->PR_SKU . "&OP_NAME=" . $option1 . "&OP_NAME2=" . $o->OP_NAME . "\">Get a Quotation</a></div>";
```

The problem Im having is when I click the button the URL it takes me too displays the $sku but not $option1.

If anyone can spot where Ive gone wrong I would really appreciate your advice. Thanks!

Comment: Why not using a form with method get?

Comment: echo statement from php is not going to work with JavaScript.

Comment: You can use `window.open()` or `location` to get this. Just fetch the selected index and redirect there using javascript with either of the above suggestions

Comment: option1 is not PHP variable. Its JS variable.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not run while the page is active, it's only run until the page is loaded. From there you have to rely on javascript.

If `$product->PR_SKU` and `$o->OP_NAME` is set by PHP you don't have to change that part, but remove `OP_NAME` from the url. After getting the option selected you can then add the parameter by javascript.

Notice that you might want to store the baseUrl somewhere else instead of writing like below, where you will potentially get duplicates of the parameter:

```
document.getElementById("your-link").href += "&OP_NAME=" + option1;
```

Do like this instead:

```
var baseUrl = <?php echo "/quotation/index.php?sku=" . $product->PR_SKU . "&OP_NAME2=" . $o->OP_NAME; ?>

var sel = document.getElementById("ADDITIONALINFO");
sel.onchange = function()
{
    var option1 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("your-link").href = baseUrl + "&OP_NAME=" + option1;
};
```

Your div can look like this (notice the removal of option1 and the `id='your-link'`:

```
<?php
echo "<div class=\"add-button-quote\"><a id=\"your-link\" href=\"/quotation/index.php?sku=" . $product->PR_SKU . "&OP_NAME2=" . $o->OP_NAME . "\">Get a Quotation</a></div>";
?>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. So how should my div look do you mean the absolute address or just the last bit? Like this?                                                     <div name="URL">                                                                   "/quotation/index.php"
</div>

Comment: My bad. I accidentally referred to the div instead of the link. You need an id on your link to refer to it with javascript. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help but I just cant get it to work! The URL just shows sku and OP_NAME2. OP_NAME is not included.

Comment: I see I have a syntax error here `...href = baseUrl = "&OP_NAME"`, which should be `...href = baseUrl + "&OP_NAME"`. And I have to ask, is there a reason you _have_ to do this with javascript? As others have said, it's possible to include the variable by using the default form in HTML.

Comment: I have tried using a form aswell. However it doesn't add the variables to the url when I click the button to take me to the index page. Do you have the basic code to do this. Ive tried about 6 different ways of doing this and none of them are working. I am going to use 4 drop down boxes not just the one eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an id and change javascript function to:

```
sel.onchange = function()
{
    var option1 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("add-button-quote").innerHTML = "<a href='/quotation/index.php?sku=<?php echo $product->PR_SKU;?>&OP_NAME="+encodeURIComponent(option1)+"&OP_NAME2=<?php echo $o->OP_NAME;?>'>Get a Quotation</a>";
    alert(option1);
};
```

Or give anchor an id and the same way manipulate its href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of form with POST method with javascript onchange event -etched- directly to select tag. This should work *(haven't tested though) and if it does, it won't take a lot of Your time to adapt this to GET instead of POST.

```
<form id="UNIQUEID" method="POST" action="#">
    <select id="ADDITIONALINFO" name="ADDITIONALINFO" onchange="document.forms['UNIQUEID'].submit();">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

One more thing...

USE singlequotes when mixing php and html - wherever possible and don't forget to write php close tag.. **?>** - ALSO .. this -> **&** should be **&amp;** inside href tag when url query is not -text/plain- (javascript) but -text/html-.

Example with php shortEcho:

`<?=` instead of `<?php echo` (I assume that Your server is configured to use php shorthands):

```
<?='<div class="add-button-quote"> <a href="/quotation/index.php?sku='.$product->PR_SKU.'&amp;OP_NAME='.$option1.'&amp;OP_NAME2='.$o->OP_NAME.'">Get a Quotation</a> </div>'; ?>
```

HOwever, as people already stated here, $option1 variable is not going to work on the way You want.

With additional `$option1=$_GET['ADDITIONALINFO'];` or `$option1=$_POST['ADDITIONALINFO'];` (whichever You decide to use, depending on form method) somewhere in between, and before `<div class="add-button-quote">` .. might work. :)

Answer (score -1):

$option1 is not defined in PHP (it's a variable in JavaScript, right?) You can not mix up JS and php in that way ;)

Comment: Ahh okay so how can I add that JS value to the URL?

Comment: One solution would be to use a form instead of this all, it would handle all this. If you really want to do it with JS you could add an event listener to your link which is called, when the link is clicked, prevent the default behavior and use window.location.href = "yourlinkwithoutoption1&OP_NAME=" + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

Answer (score -1):

Use onclick instead of onchange, it should do the trick...Like @Florian asks, why not using a form?

Also, you should define option1 outside onclick/onchange scope, and use it as a javascript variable, without '$', once it is not a PHP variable

Comment: Okay how do I do this? :P